# Relation does not exist with Django uwsgi spooler function

Tags: python, django, uwsgi, psycopg2

I'm running a Django 1.8 app using uwsgi. I'm trying to run a function in a spooler using the @spool decorator. The function is adding data to my models.

But I get this error when the spooler function tries to save an object:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "bgsite_person" does not exist
LINE 1: UPDATE "bgsite_person" SET "title" = NULL, "first_names" = N...
```

Here's my uwsgi config file:

```
[uwsgi]
http = :8000
module = BGMS.wsgi:application
chdir = /home/pete/GitHub/BGMS/BGMS
check-static = /home/pete/GitHub/BGMS/BGMS/BGMS/build/
home = /home/pete/.virtualenvs/bgms
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=BGMS.settings.development

master = true
processes = 4
threads = 1
lazy-apps = 1

spooler = /home/pete/Documents/
shared-import = /home/pete/GitHub/BGMS/BGMS/bgsite/spooler_functions.py
```

I've no problems when I run this function in a normal worker.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Can you run `python manage.py showmigrations` to see if you have ran all the migration files for your Django app? It could be that you have not run any new migrations since they last changed.

Comment: Thanks, but migrations have all been applied.